# Java Hibernate Many To One Question

Tags: java, hibernate

I am having problem with my Hibernate Mapping.
I have a many to one mapping between my entity.
The two tables in my Oracle DB are the following...

```
Employee                                                                                                                                                      
--------------------------
EMPLOYEE_ID  
EMPLOYEE_FIRST_NAME   
EMPLOYEE_LAST_NAME   
HEALTH_PLAN_ID                                                                                                                                                   
Health_Plan
------------------=
HEALTH_PLAN_ID
HEALTH_PLAN_NAME
HEALTH_PLAN_RATE
```

And my mapping...

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "employee_seq", sequenceName = "employee_seq")
public class Employee {
    private int employeeId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private HealthPlan plan;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "employee_seq")
    @Column(name = "employee_id", nullable = false)
    public int getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }
    @Column(name = "employee_first_name", nullable = false)
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    @Column(name = "employee_last_name", nullable = false)
    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HEALTH_PLAN_ID")
    public HealthPlan getPlan() {
        return plan;
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "HEALTH_PLAN")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "HEALTH_PLAN_SEQ", sequenceName = "HEALTH_PLAN_SEQ")
public class HealthPlan {
    private int healthPlanId;
    private String healthPlanName;
    private double healthPlanRate;
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "HEALTH_PLAN_SEQ")
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "HEALTH_PLAN_ID")
    public int getHealthPlanId() {
        return healthPlanId;
    }
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "HEALTH_PLAN_NAME", unique = true)
    public String getHealthPlanName() {
        return healthPlanName;
    }
    @Column(nullable = false, name = "HEALTH_PLAN_RATE")
    public double getHealthPlanRate() {
        return healthPlanRate;
    }
}
```

When I ran below code....

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {        
        HealthPlanDaoImpl healthDao = new HealthPlanDaoImpl();
        EmployeeDaoImpl empDao = new EmployeeDaoImpl();

        HealthPlan plan = new HealthPlan();
        plan.setHealthPlanName("PLAN B");
        plan.setHealthPlanRate(5.0);

        Employee emp = new Employee();
        emp.setPlan(plan);
        emp.setFirstName("Jane");
        emp.setLastName("Doe");
        boolean isSuccess = empDao.addEmployee(emp);
        System.out.println(isSuccess);

    }
public class EmployeeDaoImpl{
    public  boolean addEmployee(Employee emp) {
      boolean bolReturn = true;

      Session session = HibernateUtil.beginTransaction();
      try {
          session.save(emp);
          HibernateUtil.commitTransaction();
      } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
          bolReturn = false;
          HibernateUtil.rollbackTransaction();
      } 
      return bolReturn;
    }
}
```

In the Health_Plan Table, the HEALTH_PLAN_ID = 3 (Which is correct!!!)
In the Employee Table, the HEALTH_PLAN_ID = 1850 (Where did this value came from???  I expect this to be 3 also.)

I tried several times and I notice that in the Employee Table HEALTH_PLAN_ID just increment by 300.
I think I already set the cascade option.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
HealthPlan plan = new HealthPlan();
plan.setHealthPlanName("PLAN B");
plan.setHealthPlanRate(5.0);

Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setPlan(plan);
emp.setFirstName("Jane");
emp.setLastName("Doe");
```

creates a new `HealthPlan` instance for every `Employee` instance created. The original `HealthPlan` instance is not used in a new mapping between a new `Employee` and an existing `HealthPlan`. If you query for the existing `HealthPlan` instance, and then set it to every `Employee`, you will find that the health plan id will be consistent across objects.

The discrepancy in the values for the HEALTH_PLAN_ID values can be attributed to the afore mentioned behavior of your test code. Also, the sequence allocation size would have been incremented by 50, which is the default, and you happen to be seeing the result of six consecutive sequence increment operations. Note, that Hibernate will update sequences in a different transaction, so you will find that the sequence values will increment even if you rollback the current transaction.

On a different note, I would advise against using a unidirectional `@ManyToOne` relationship with a `CascadeType` value of ALL. Do you really want to delete the `HealthPlan` of all `Employee` instances if one `Employee` is removed, or for that matter, allow updates of `HealthPlan` instances from an Employee to be propagated for merge events?

Comment: I think I got your first point regarding the HealthPlan.  I think the healthplan should be present when I save my employee instance.  On the second point, what should be the ideal CascadeType Option? Thanks

Comment: @Mark, I would suggest using a bidirectional `@ManyToOne` (by a specifying a `@OneToMany` `Set` or `List` of `Employee` instances in `HealthPlan`) instead of a unidirectional `@ManyToOne`; you would then be specifying the cascadetype on the inverse `@OneToMany` declaration in `HealthPlan` instead. You can then specify a cascadetype of ALL on the `@OneToMany` annotation instead of the `@ManyToOne` annotation.

Comment: this is one concept in Hibernate where I am struggling to understand.. Do I really need to configure the association at both ends of the entity?  I mean, when I perform a query, isn't it logical to perform it with the Employee Entity with a particular health plan.  Or should I do it with the Healthplan entity and retrieve the list of Employees with this Healthplan? Also, in terms of performance, which one is faster?  Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Your query can be rephrased as whether you need a bi-directional or a unidirectional `@ManyToOne` relationship, or a unidirectional `@OneToMany` relationship. Well, the answer to that would be - go with a `OneToMany` relationship first, and then decide on making it bidirectional depending on whether you want to access `HealthPlan` instances from an `Employee` instance. I would prefer using a `@OneToMany` instead of a `@ManyToOne` relation, as managing the `Employee` collection is easier than managing the `HealthPlan` reference. contd.

Comment: To add to one of my previous comments, you can opt for a `ManyToOne` relationship, if your object model desires that you access the `HealthPlan` from an `Employee`, instead of accessing `Employee`s from a `HealthPlan`. In this case, I would definitely avoid using `CascadeType.ALL` and `CascadeType.REMOVE` on the relationship; I would also avoid cascading other persistence events, except for REFRESH maybe, and have a separate Service implementation to manage `HealthPlan`s. All of this would of course, depend on your domain model.

Comment: @Vineer.. Thanks for extended help... Learned quite a few today.. =)

Comment: @VineetReynolds let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2655/discussion-between-mark-estrada-and-vineet-reynolds)

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the exact reason of the issue , but I can see some issues with the code right away .
1.In health plan table the annotation says GenerationType.SEQUENCE where as in the employee table it says GenerationType.AUTO
2.In the employee table @Column(name = "**employee_id**", nullable = false) . employee_id is neither the name of the variable in the entity class nor the name of the actual column. Three columns in that entity class has this problem .

Probably if you fix this, it can solve your issue ?

Comment: The name in the `@Column` annotation represents a table column name and not an entity attribute name (which is pointless). Besides, Oracle column names are case insensitive by default, unless they are quoted, so `@Column(name = "employee_id" ...` actually maps to `Employee.EMPLOYEE_ID`.